# Adding Custom Refrence for ASP.Net MVC on Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

We are developing an ASP.Net MVC project and some of my co-workers are working on Mac OS. I have installed Visual Studio Code and ASP.Net Helper along with the C#. I have copied the whole project to Mac but the problem is it is not seeing my project refrence file, let's say MyProject.dll. When i add it on the Windows with generic VS, IntelliSense is completing automatically bringing the functions that i wrote.

All i need is adding a refrence and using IntelliSense for my functions on VisualStudio code. Is there anyway to achive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code doesn't support ASP.NET MVC projects. You can load them and view files but you will not be able to use Intellisense, build or debug such projects. If you want your co-workers to use VS Code as the IDE under Mac consider migrating your project to ASP.NET Core.